# How to make rich cards optional bot framework

Tags: botframework

When a user gets their question answered, the bot would create a rich card with two buttons: 'Yes' and 'No', Yes if the answer is good, No if the answer is bad. If the user decides not to click any of the buttons and decides to ask another question, how would do I get them back to the root dialog? Any suggestion would be great!

```html
public async Task CreateSurvey(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity activity)
{
    var reply = context.MakeMessage();
    reply.Text = activity.Text;
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    var actions = new List<CardAction>();
    actions.Add(new CardAction { Title = $"Yes", Value = $"Yes" });
    actions.Add(new CardAction { Title = $"No", Value = $"No" });

    var card = new HeroCard() { Title = "My Survey", Buttons = actions };
    reply.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());
    reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;

    await context.PostAsync(reply);
    context.Wait<IMessageActivity>(GetSurveyResponse);
}

private async Task GetSurveyResponse(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity activity)
{
    if (activity.Text == "Yes")
    {
        context.Done("Good answer!");
    }
    else if (activity.Text == "No")
    {
        context.Done("Bad answer!");
    }
    else
    {
        // Continue to root dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: The survey is also in the RootDialog or is in a child dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dialog - SurveyDialog, place you code in this dialog. Call SurveyDialog from RootDialog. Mark context.Done() in the else case. Your dialog control will be resumed in method passed in RootDialog. Please let me know if this does not help or you requirement is something else.

Answer (score 0):

As the reference on official site:

> In C#, you can use `context.Wait()` to specify the callback to invoke the next time the user sends a message. To close a dialog and remove it from the stack (thereby sending the user back to the prior dialog in the stack), use `context.Done()`. You must end every dialog method with `context.Wait()`, `context.Fail()`, `context.Done()`, or some redirection directive such as `context.Forward()` or `context.Call()`. A dialog method that does not end with one of these will result in an error (because the framework does not know what action to take the next time the user sends a message).

Additionally, you can leverage state data to store your previous data if you need:

```
var selectedCard = await result;
context.UserData.SetValue("selection", selectedCard.Text);
```